# onRequestPermissionsResult has an empty permission and grantResults arrays, even when permission is granted

Tags: android, kotlin

I understand from the Android docs that the `permissions` and `grantResults` arrays will be empty in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` if the dialog is cancelled, but in my case, the dialog shows up, I allow the location permissions, and then it shows the toast because the permissions and grantResults arrays are empty.

What might be causing this?

Here is the code requesting and receiving the permission:

```
    private fun requestLocationPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<out String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                bindLocationManager()
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on location access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Had you defined any other location permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` like `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: just a small note: If you call ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in a fragment, the onRequestPermissionsResult callback is called on the activity and not the fragment

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes I believe both coarse and fine are defined in the manifest

Comment: @Kushan this is in main activity, so I think that should be okay.  That was one of my first thoughts as well

Comment: @cpgreen2 Then you need to ask both the permissions not one